# remove tooltip space between border and content highcharts

Tags: graph, highcharts, report

i'm using highcharts for genetating graphs, problem is, highcharts is generating space between border and content of **Tooltip** and labels of the Pie diagram is visible between that generated space.
can any has solving for my problem.

Please check with below example.

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'graf1',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },

            title: {
                margin: 40,
                text: 'Podíl všech potřeb'
            },
            tooltip: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
                borderRadius: 0,
                shadow: false,
                useHTML: true,
                percentageDecimals: 2,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<div class="tooltop">'+this.point.name + '<br />' + '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y).replace(",", " ") + ' Kč [' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + '%]</b></div>';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        zIndex: 1,
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorWidth: 2,
                        useHTML: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '"><b>' + this.point.name + '</b></span>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Potřeba',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox', 45.0],
                    ['IE', 26.8], {
                        name: 'Chrome',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    }, ['Safari', 8.5],
                    ['Opera', 6.2],
                    ['Others', 0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.label {
 z-index: 1!important;
}

.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid green;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:9999!important;
}

.tooltip {
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="graf1" style="width: 400px; height: 250px; float:left"></div>
```

tooltip space between order and content highcharts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG tooltip elements can be hidden through:

```
        tooltip: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            shadow: false,
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x8Lq0yr9/1/

This will eliminate the space between border and HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

you are using div class="tooltop" where as tooltop class is nowhere. Also, .highcharts-tooltip is used in highcharts at two places . one at datalables and second in tiiptip. 
Unless you want specific border color , you can remove that css class from your code and tooltip loks good.

```
 .tooltipSpan {    
opacity:1;
z-index:9999!important;
 width:100%;
}
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/jxwcjn30/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts creates these using svg which makes it so the background shows up underneath certain elements. To avoid this undesired behavior the border and background settings have been turned off and all these are controlled, instead, using html in the formatter function. Using HTML makes it so the background does not show up underneath certain elements.

```
tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: undefined,
    borderColor: undefined,
    borderWidth: 0,
}
```

Comment: And you can then use `tooltip: { style: { backgroundColor: '#060B17' } } ` to decorate your tooltip.